# How do I pass an ArrayList to a method expecting a vararg (Object...)?

Tags: java

Assume a method with the following signature:

```
public static void foo(String arg1, String args2, Object... moreArgs);
```

When running ...

```
ClassName.foo("something", "something", "first", "second", "third");
```

... I'll get `moreArgs[0] == "first"`, `moreArgs[1] == "second"` and `moreArgs[2] == "third"`.

But assume that I have the parameters stored in an `ArrayList<String>` called `arrayList` which contains "first", "second" and "third".

I want to call `foo` so that `moreArgs[0] == "first"`, `moreArgs[1] == "second"` and `moreArgs[2] == "third"` using the `arrayList` as a parameter.

My naïve attempt was ...

```
ClassName.foo("something", "something", arrayList);
```

... but that will give me `moreArgs[0] == arrayList` which is not what I wanted.

What is the correct way to pass `arrayList` to the `foo` method above so that `moreArgs[0] == "first"`, `moreArgs[1] == "second"` and `moreArgs[2] == "third"`?

Please note that the number of arguments in `arrayList` happens to be three in this specific case, but the solution I'm looking for should obviously be general and work for any number of arguments in `arrayList`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Convert your ArrayList into an Array of type object.

```
ClassName.foo("something", "something", arrayList.toArray());
```

Comment: Oh, it was that simple! I thought Object... != Object[]. Thanks! :-)

Comment: In general Object != Object[], but for varargs methods, the compiler converts a MyType... parameter into a MyType[] parameter, and wraps all arguments into an array at runtime which gets passed to the function. So in this case, you get to take advantage of the secret internal signature of the varargs method by explicitly passing in an array reference.

Answer (score -1):

You pass it just how you expect. However there is only one thing, and it is the reference to the ArrayList.

You then have to shift your stuff off the array list.

Comment: I can only control the code calling the foo method, so changing the foo method is not an option.